# JS Function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently working on a school project and one of my functions is not running, onclick. I dont know why. I know its the function because i added a console.log() command.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="popup">
        <div id="contain">
            <div id="advert"><a href="#" onclick="close()" id="close">close</a></div>
        </div>
        <div id="block"></div>
        </div>
```

**JS:**

```
function close(){
                console.log("worked");
                $("#popup").hide();
            };
```

Comment: [`close()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close) as a global is already taken by the browser. Try renaming the function to `closePopup()` or similar to avoid the conflict.

Comment: This is one reason why you shouldn't use inline event handlers in global scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function closePopup(){
  console.log("worked");
  $("#popup").hide();
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="popup">
        <div id="contain">
            <div id="advert"><a href="#" onclick="closePopup()" id="close">close</a></div>
        </div>
        <div id="block"></div>
</div>
```

Your code didn't work because, **close** is an inbuilt function. Changing the name of the function do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You named your function `close`, which is reserved for `window.close()` and that is why it is not working. Just name it to something else and it will work :D cheers!